# Expected deviation between a theoretical discrete probability distribution and the simulated one resulting from a number of trials

Tags: probability, distributions, standard-deviation, simulation

Suppose we have seven colors, each associated with a theoretical probability to choose one of them. The probabilities are as follows:
red ______ 0.304761904761905 
blue _____ 0.304761904761905 
yellow ___ 0.304761904761905 
green ____ 0.021428571428571 
purple ___ 0.021428571428571 
cyan _____ 0.021428571428571 
magenta __ 0.021428571428571 

Question 1 : We run a simulation in which we pick up a random color 10000 times according to the above probability distribution. By measuring how many times we picked up each color, we may deduce a simulated probability distribution. What is the expected deviation between the two probability distributions? Is there a mathematical formula to determine it? 
Assume for this and the following question that if the deviation per color is dev(c) where c is the color, then the single criterion for the aforementioned deviation would be max(dev(c)).
Question 2 : If we want the deviation between the theoretical and simulated probability not to exceed 0.001, how can we determine the number of trials that must be performed? Is there a mathematical formula to determine it?

Comment: Where you say: "What is the expected deviation between the two probability distributions?"  --- What measure of deviation are you using to summarize the seven differences in distribution?

Comment: A project submission of mine was rejected with the message "Sampling results are off by more than the allowable tolerance limit (0.001)". "Tolerance limit" reminds me of deviation.
If P is the theoretical probability and Q is the simulated probability, a naive measure of deviation might be dev(c) = abs(P(c)-Q(c)), (c:color) and of summarized deviation  D=max(dev(c)). Run 100 tests with 10000 trials each and checked in how many tests D>limit.
For limit 0.001: 100.
For limit 0.01: 5.
I believe that "Tolerance limit" should be 0.01, not 0.001. But this is no proof.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. Where does this tolerance limit come from?

Comment: The "tolerance limit" is a threshold used by the course's grader: if my simulated probabilities differ from the theoretical ones more than the tolerance limit, the submission is rejected. I do not know how they calculate it.

Comment: A couple of points: 1. The absolute difference in probability is a possible measure, sure - but so would many other things; e.g. relative difference, standardized difference, etc $\,$ 2. In any case, you will have seven of these deviations. It seems that the answer to *how are you summarizing these differences* is "taking the largest". You should make that explicit. 3. The absolute difference will tend to be larger for the larger probabilities, so if that's the criterion, you'll hit the problem in those categories nearly all of the time, which offers a possible path to simplifying things.

Comment: The distribution of the largest absolute deviation is kind of complicated when the proportions differ. I'd simulate, personally, However, you already have a simulation at one sample size; note that multiplying the sample size by a factor $k$ will reduce the spread due to random sampling by a multiplicative factor of $1/\sqrt{k}$, so that should help in getting your sample size quickly to the ballpark. (e.g. quadruple the simulation size will halve the spread and halve the typical size of the absolute deviations). So if you want to make the absolute error one tenth as large, take $10^2$ x 10000

Comment: @Glen_b [a] How is the relative difference defined? [b] By "standardized difference" we mean the classic standard deviation? [c] Sorry for the naive question: When you say "you should make this explicit", you mean I should update the post?

Comment: (a) typically (value - theoretical.value)/theoretical.value which is the same as value/theoretical.value - 1 (you'd look at the absolute value of these, say). A closely related measure is the difference of the logs.  (b) no, the difference (value - theoretical) divided by its standard error (again you might look at its absolute value, or in this case, you might look at its square). (c) yes, your post should be clear about explaining how you see the 7 'deviations' being turned into a single criterion.

Comment: This is a multinomial distribution with probabilities $(128,128,128,9,9,9,9)/420.$ That gives the mathematical formula for what to expect.  The solution to question 2 is most easily approximated with an analysis based on a Normal distribution: namely, to find a sample size where the *maximum* deviation between the 7 observed frequencies and theoretical probabilities does not exceed $0.001$ (or something small like that). Although there's a formula, it needs to be numerically evaluated anyway.

Comment: @Glen_b: Regarding the standardized difference: the error is the sum over all colors for (value - theoretical)^2?

Comment: @whuber:[a] Which is the method to produce (128,128,128,9,9,9,9)/420 from the supplied probabilities? [b]   Need a clarification regarding question's 2 approximation:  This involves the approximation of the multinomial distribution by a set of seven independent binomial distributions and then (for large number of trials) by approximating each of these with a normal distribution?

Comment: (a) Arithmetic. (b) It would be better to account for the slight negative correlation and use a multivariate Normal distribution whose moments match those of the multinomial distribution.

Comment: @TimoSL To return to my earlier point, the ability for the small proportions to show deviation (due to random sampling) from their population mean is much less than the ability of the large proportions. (Large proportions have a [larger standard error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cBwZ.png)). So a deviation of 0.13 for one of your small proportions would be shocking but for one of your large proportions the same deviation is unremarkable. Just adding their squares will lead to focusing on the deviations on the large probabilities.